# Best way to place a proxy in a network?

Tags: router, lan, proxy

Correct me if I am wrong, but in a LAN, when a packet sent by a computer has a destination located in the Internet, it will send it to the gateway (which is a router only right?).

Now, I want to implement a proxy. I was thinking about setting the proxy as a gateway. The proxy will then redirect packets to the router.

Is it the good way? If not, what is the other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specific, if the packet is not on the connected network, the computer will forward it to the address (next-hop) based on the longest match in the routing table.  For most computers, there is only one route in the table, known as the default route. The next-hop of the default route is usually called the default gateway.

The gateway is often a router, but it can be another device such as a firewall.

Proxies are application-specific -- they are application-layer devices.  So you would not configure the proxy as the default gateway.  Instead, you would configure the application to forward packets to the proxy.  Because it is an application-layer device, the proxy can be anywhere in the network, although it is common to put it in a DMZ network.